# How to create an admin panel for a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, wordpress, express

I created an online store website on React. Now, the data is loaded from a local .json file. I also need to create an admin panel so that the site administrator can add/change/delete cards and data himself. How can this be done? Is there an opportunity not to write a backend?
P.S. I tried to use Wordpress, but I don't understand how. I don't need to create a wordpress site, I only need an admin panel to which I will make fetch requests in my React application.

I tried to create a Wordpress admin panel using Pods but I can't understand how to display my data in the admin panel.

RESULT: The Strapi app helped me with setting a database easibly changeable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

local.json is your database base on JSON, for edit or delete this file you need access file system and if you want just work on local host, you can get file in your panel after done your edit, create file with new Blob and name it local.json and download it with your browser and download and replace with last local.json file, but if you want do it more like real apps yes you need backed language like node.js to access file system to edit or delete your local.json file.

this like is help for create and download your local.json file
[How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)

Comment: I needed to set up a database. I did it by the usage of Strapi.